# Cannot reinstall OSX Mac mini 6,1

Tags: macos, mac-mini, install

I've been trying to install Ubuntu server on my Mac mini 6,1 with no success.
However now I'm stuck and can't even reinstall OSX from a USB key. I've created it on my MBPr, and tested it there : it works fine.

Now when I try to boot from it in the Mac mini, I get a grey crossed-circle and the Mac mini shuts down.

Does anybody knows a way to fix that ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can hold down the keys **[cmd]** + **[r]** while the mini is shut down and then push the power button. This should lead you to the recovery via the Mac App Store.

Take a look at:

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4718?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

Answer (score 1):

The crossed circle means you are trying to launch an unsupported version of Lion.You'll need the right version, best to Format/Reinstall via the Lion Internet Recovery function by pressing cmd+option+r on startup.

If this doesn't work, you may need to reformat and wipe the drive on another machine before it can be used.

Finally if all else fails it could be a hardware incompatibility, try and remember if you've changed anything recently, it could seem innocuous at first but little things can make big problems.